# MVC EF Database first many to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can somebody clarify how many to many relationship works in EF Database first.
For example `Student` and `Course` table where the relationship is many to many. I already have a database.

So I have created an `.edmx`

The classes for `Student` and `Courses` are created auto. And I have added a new class in called `StudentCourseViewModel.cs`. Where the idea was to control the relationship with it. 
My `StudentCourseViewModel` containts the following:

```
public class StudentCourseViewModel
{
    public Student Student{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllCourses{ get; set; }    
    private List<int> _selectedCourse;
    public List<int> SelectedCourse
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedCourse == null)
            {
                _selectedCourse = Student.Courses.Select(m => m.pkID).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedCourse;
        }
        set { _selectedCourse = value; }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(db.Courses, "pkID", "Name"); 
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create(StudentCourseViewModel model,[Bind(Include = "pkID,Name")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (student == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        // Remove items that were unselected
        db.Courses.Where(m => !model.SelectedCourses
            .Contains(m.pkID))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => student.Courses.Remove(m));

        // Add newly selected items
        var existingClientIds = student.Courses.Select(m => m.pkID).ToList();
        db.Courses.Where(m => model.SelectedCourses.Except(existingClientIds)
            .Contains(m.pkID))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(m => student.Courses.Add(m));

        db.students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

I would like to now how to handle the  // GET: `/Create` and  // POST: `/Create`
and also how to view the list of courses in the `create.cshtml`? 
I get the following error with the above code:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: How is the relationship mapped in the database, do you have an intermediate `StudentCourse` mapping table? It is not clear how your "ViewModel" would map the relationship in any way.

Comment: Hey ja I have an intermediate StudentCourse table in the data base, but when I created the .edmx, the StudentCourse table is not shown in the model it is instead a link which states many to many with "*" sign.

Comment: It sounds like it is correctly mapped already, you don't get a class generated for your intermediate table ef just populates the relevant navigation properties. What is it in your controller/view that you are having a problem with?

Comment: Im having problem updating the Student with other words when I create a new Student. I have added the following to Get /create function  ViewBag.Courses= new SelectList(db.Courses, "pkID", "Name");  and it works I got a list in the create view were I can select, and here is the problem how to modify Post/Create function to save it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Saving many to many relationships can be a little tricky as if you're not careful, EF can get confused and think you're trying to readd existing items and give you integrity errors.

You're already using a view model with a property that holds a list of ints. That's good. Half the battle is won. Now, all you need is some logic to query the selected courses and add them to the `Courses` collection:

```
// Remove items that were unselected
db.Courses.Where(m => !model.SelectedCourse.Contains(m.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => student.Courses.Remove(m));

// Add newly selected items
var existingCourseIds = student.Courses.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
db.Courses.Where(m => model.SelectedCourse.Except(existingCourseIds).Contains(m.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => student.Courses.Add(m));
```

Technically, that's only necessary if you're editing an existing student. It shouldn't hurt to use the same code for either create or edit, but for create it *can* be simplified to just:

```
student.Courses = db.Courses.Where(m => model.SelectedCourse.Contains(m.Id));
```

Since you're creating a brand new student, there's no existing relationships to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I have added `ViewBag.Courses= new SelectList(db.Courses, "pkID", "Name");` to the get/create function and it gives a list of courses to select from in the create view.  now when I select a course and type create I got error on the line                 `db.SaveChanges();` , And thats because the fetched data does not match with the db, so what I dont know how to solve is how to fix that, should I pass a StudentCourseViewModel parameter to the post/create function ? and how to fix the relationship and save?

Comment: I'm not following you. Perhaps, update your question with the existing code you have and include the code for your action(s).

Comment: Oh I see it is not that easy to explain, I have now updated the question with code. My problem is I dont understand how to handle the many to many relationship, and I could not find a good explanation of that for a database first, I have found for code first.